# UITableView Search Display Cell Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

definedNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ohio", @"Newark", @"Steve", @"Coffee", nil];

definedAmounts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"5", @"100", @"1", @"72", nil];

}
```

That for example. So the numbers go with the name it matches but when i search it puts the numbers still in that order with the searched names

before search:

[image]

searching for newark:

[image]

Newark should stay with the value 100.  Can someone explain how to do this to me please? i would appreciate it. also i have over 1000 entries and the values are shown in a custom cell.

thanks

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here, this belongs on Stack Overflow and should be migrated there automatically soon once enough people vote for it to be moved.

Comment: i have already asked this here please delete this one

Comment: If you already asked it here, don't post it on SU as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use a dictionary. The keys could be names and values could be the numbers.

```
NSDictionary *amounts = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], @"Ohio", [NSNumber numberWithInt:100], @"Newark", etc.., nil];
```

To get a number mapped to Newark:

```
NSNumber *numberNewark = [amounts objectForKey:@"Newark"];
```

An NSNumber is just a wrapper for a primitive and can be replaced where you use NSString, it writes out the number it wraps. Example NSLog(@"%@", numberNewark); will write '100' to console.